# Footer only appears on scroll with offset

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues with offseting the footer ID with javascript

Transform creates a new local coordinate system(W3C Spec), position: fixed is fixed to the origin of scrollbar content container ( `main` ), i.e. the left: 0, top: 0 point.

This is why I need to register a scroll listener and apply offsets to the fixed elements.

The problem I'm having is that the footer only appears on scroll, I want it to be in position on load like my `header` - otherwise everything works perfectly

I am still a beginner with Javascript, hoping for some suggestions

```js
var fixedElem = document.getElementById('fixed');

        var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
        document.getElementById('scroll'),
        );

        scrollbar.addListener(function(status) {
        var offset = status.offset;
        
        fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
        fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
        
        footer.style.top = (offset.y + document.getElementById('scroll').clientHeight - footer.clientHeight) + 'px';
        });
```

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/master/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main id="scroll">
    <header id="fixed">
      <h1>A fixed header</h1>
    </header>
    <article id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio amet, laudantium et ex, maiores labore minima quis incidunt quam magnam molestias, temporibus commodi! Laborum ipsam et aut quibusdam veniam animi.</p>
      <p>Illo, obcaecati modi laudantium, impedit ab dolorem optio sint fuga nisi, est earum, aliquam! Nam officia doloribus ad, facere architecto voluptatem labore, minima dicta dignissimos cumque ut assumenda, natus et!</p>
      <p>Odio velit vitae nisi consectetur molestiae repudiandae nemo quia qui in voluptatibus rerum iusto minus atque accusamus, autem, expedita incidunt magni voluptate itaque iure et cupiditate? Praesentium consectetur nesciunt at!</p>
      <p>Hic obcaecati laboriosam impedit doloribus numquam officia atque quia voluptatem deleniti sint ipsum debitis excepturi modi non tenetur corporis maxime magni aliquid, facere, saepe omnis, iusto architecto, aspernatur iste. Quae?</p>
      <p>Iste voluptatum rerum atque nesciunt sequi, dolore dicta error. Voluptas, quidem. Quasi aspernatur, culpa aliquid aperiam maxime sed voluptatum, saepe quis perferendis nulla sint possimus cumque, magnam voluptates hic accusantium?</p>
      <p>Ipsum, voluptates rerum repellendus illo fugiat, non aspernatur iure accusamus ullam recusandae quos? Veritatis accusantium, laudantium possimus rem, pariatur maxime itaque mollitia eos sapiente illum dolor adipisci ratione laborum iure.</p>
      <p>Laboriosam eius ipsum recusandae fuga aut nobis aperiam, veritatis ullam quod voluptatibus voluptatem voluptates labore quisquam ut tempora blanditiis cum, eaque illo nam sapiente autem debitis! Unde, quod necessitatibus cum?</p>
      <p>Sapiente iure distinctio vel qui enim, molestiae rerum fugit at non voluptate numquam doloremque a, obcaecati fugiat et debitis, magni alias eveniet cupiditate veritatis natus voluptates nostrum reprehenderit. Quidem, quam.</p>
      <p>Id fugiat at tenetur, architecto enim inventore accusamus asperiores quod! Dicta modi omnis sunt, laboriosam expedita et, ullam vel culpa odit consequuntur nobis provident id excepturi. Distinctio veniam, fuga temporibus?</p>
      <p>Voluptate soluta, sapiente quaerat, nulla iste similique adipisci natus amet. Deleniti perspiciatis, qui saepe, reprehenderit vero excepturi quo beatae at autem sed repellendus maxime repudiandae, tempore obcaecati similique! Distinctio, consequuntur!</p>
    </article>
     <footer id="footer">
       <h1>A fixed footer</h1>
     </footer>
     </main>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the top offset of the footer initially to 100%. That way, the footer just disappears just right below the bottom. Substract the height from the view height and you'll see it.

```
#footer {
  ...
  top: calc(100vh - 37px);
  ...
}
```

Another way is to initialize the offset yourself manually:

```
function setOffset(status) {
  var offset = status.offset;

  fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
  fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';

  footer.style.top = (offset.y + document.getElementById('scroll').clientHeight - footer.clientHeight) + 'px';
}

scrollbar.addListener(setOffset);
setOffset({ offset: { y: 0 }});
```

Nevertheless there is also `position: sticky;`, which is quite useful for headers and footers. In that case you would only need to set the scrollbar to the `#content`. I didn't get it to work properly in combination with the scrollbar, but maybe you want to think about it. (SEE EDIT)

```js
var fixedElem = document.getElementById('fixed');

var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
  document.getElementById('scroll'),
);

function setOffset(status) {
  var offset = status.offset;

  fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
  fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';

  footer.style.top = (offset.y + document.getElementById('scroll').clientHeight - footer.clientHeight) + 'px';
}

scrollbar.addListener(setOffset);
//setOffset({ offset: { y: 0 }});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100vh - 37px);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/master/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="scroll">
    <header id="fixed">
      <h1>A fixed header</h1>
    </header>
    <article id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio amet, laudantium et ex, maiores labore minima quis incidunt quam magnam molestias, temporibus commodi! Laborum ipsam et aut quibusdam veniam animi.</p>
      <p>Illo, obcaecati modi laudantium, impedit ab dolorem optio sint fuga nisi, est earum, aliquam! Nam officia doloribus ad, facere architecto voluptatem labore, minima dicta dignissimos cumque ut assumenda, natus et!</p>
      <p>Odio velit vitae nisi consectetur molestiae repudiandae nemo quia qui in voluptatibus rerum iusto minus atque accusamus, autem, expedita incidunt magni voluptate itaque iure et cupiditate? Praesentium consectetur nesciunt at!</p>
      <p>Hic obcaecati laboriosam impedit doloribus numquam officia atque quia voluptatem deleniti sint ipsum debitis excepturi modi non tenetur corporis maxime magni aliquid, facere, saepe omnis, iusto architecto, aspernatur iste. Quae?</p>
      <p>Iste voluptatum rerum atque nesciunt sequi, dolore dicta error. Voluptas, quidem. Quasi aspernatur, culpa aliquid aperiam maxime sed voluptatum, saepe quis perferendis nulla sint possimus cumque, magnam voluptates hic accusantium?</p>
      <p>Ipsum, voluptates rerum repellendus illo fugiat, non aspernatur iure accusamus ullam recusandae quos? Veritatis accusantium, laudantium possimus rem, pariatur maxime itaque mollitia eos sapiente illum dolor adipisci ratione laborum iure.</p>
      <p>Laboriosam eius ipsum recusandae fuga aut nobis aperiam, veritatis ullam quod voluptatibus voluptatem voluptates labore quisquam ut tempora blanditiis cum, eaque illo nam sapiente autem debitis! Unde, quod necessitatibus cum?</p>
      <p>Sapiente iure distinctio vel qui enim, molestiae rerum fugit at non voluptate numquam doloremque a, obcaecati fugiat et debitis, magni alias eveniet cupiditate veritatis natus voluptates nostrum reprehenderit. Quidem, quam.</p>
      <p>Id fugiat at tenetur, architecto enim inventore accusamus asperiores quod! Dicta modi omnis sunt, laboriosam expedita et, ullam vel culpa odit consequuntur nobis provident id excepturi. Distinctio veniam, fuga temporibus?</p>
      <p>Voluptate soluta, sapiente quaerat, nulla iste similique adipisci natus amet. Deleniti perspiciatis, qui saepe, reprehenderit vero excepturi quo beatae at autem sed repellendus maxime repudiandae, tempore obcaecati similique! Distinctio, consequuntur!</p>
    </article>
    <footer id="footer">
      <h1>A fixed footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**: 
I made the experience it's a good choice to always prefer css solutions to js solutions, since it's a lot less buggy and annoying. So here I added a solo css solution for the header and footer problem. NOTE: I also edited the html to do so:

```js
var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
  document.getElementById('scroll'),
);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

footer {
  position: sticky;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* substract header and footer size */
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  overflow: auto;
  background: orange;
}

article {
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/master/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>A fixed header</h1>
    </header>
    <main id="scroll">
      <article id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio amet, laudantium et ex, maiores labore minima quis incidunt quam magnam molestias, temporibus commodi! Laborum ipsam et aut quibusdam veniam animi.</p>
        <p>Illo, obcaecati modi laudantium, impedit ab dolorem optio sint fuga nisi, est earum, aliquam! Nam officia doloribus ad, facere architecto voluptatem labore, minima dicta dignissimos cumque ut assumenda, natus et!</p>
        <p>Odio velit vitae nisi consectetur molestiae repudiandae nemo quia qui in voluptatibus rerum iusto minus atque accusamus, autem, expedita incidunt magni voluptate itaque iure et cupiditate? Praesentium consectetur nesciunt at!</p>
        <p>Hic obcaecati laboriosam impedit doloribus numquam officia atque quia voluptatem deleniti sint ipsum debitis excepturi modi non tenetur corporis maxime magni aliquid, facere, saepe omnis, iusto architecto, aspernatur iste. Quae?</p>
        <p>Iste voluptatum rerum atque nesciunt sequi, dolore dicta error. Voluptas, quidem. Quasi aspernatur, culpa aliquid aperiam maxime sed voluptatum, saepe quis perferendis nulla sint possimus cumque, magnam voluptates hic accusantium?</p>
        <p>Ipsum, voluptates rerum repellendus illo fugiat, non aspernatur iure accusamus ullam recusandae quos? Veritatis accusantium, laudantium possimus rem, pariatur maxime itaque mollitia eos sapiente illum dolor adipisci ratione laborum iure.</p>
        <p>Laboriosam eius ipsum recusandae fuga aut nobis aperiam, veritatis ullam quod voluptatibus voluptatem voluptates labore quisquam ut tempora blanditiis cum, eaque illo nam sapiente autem debitis! Unde, quod necessitatibus cum?</p>
        <p>Sapiente iure distinctio vel qui enim, molestiae rerum fugit at non voluptate numquam doloremque a, obcaecati fugiat et debitis, magni alias eveniet cupiditate veritatis natus voluptates nostrum reprehenderit. Quidem, quam.</p>
        <p>Id fugiat at tenetur, architecto enim inventore accusamus asperiores quod! Dicta modi omnis sunt, laboriosam expedita et, ullam vel culpa odit consequuntur nobis provident id excepturi. Distinctio veniam, fuga temporibus?</p>
        <p>Voluptate soluta, sapiente quaerat, nulla iste similique adipisci natus amet. Deleniti perspiciatis, qui saepe, reprehenderit vero excepturi quo beatae at autem sed repellendus maxime repudiandae, tempore obcaecati similique! Distinctio, consequuntur, END!</p>
      </article>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <h1>A fixed footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for this, really helped me on something I have been stuck on for a while - I am choosing your method to initialize the offset manually, the only slighty clunky thing is on browser resize the footer stay at the bottom till you scroll again - Would you recommend a function to reload page on client browser resize?

Comment: @BurgerSasha Hey, I made an edit and added a solo css solution. I do not recommend you to start with resizing handlers. JS for css issues is usually not a good solution and more often than less it's causing new problems. Sometimes it's working well for small issues, but as soon as you notice, that you need to take care of this and that and that and this, go with a css solution if there is one.